# Authorization::Roles doesn't work in Catalyst app

Tags: sql, perl, authorization, roles, catalyst

I've tried use Authorization::Roles in my Catalyst app. Authentication works right but when I use `$c->check_user_roles("admin");` it always returns false. What's wrong?

Some config:

```
store => {
    class => 'DBIx::Class',
    user_model => 'Mymodel::User',
    id_field => 'name',
    role_field => 'rolename', # in my table there is the same column
                             # name undoubtedly
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your roles are stored in the users table, use the `role_column` option. If your roles are stored in a separate table, use the `role_relation` and `role_field` options. `role_field` on its own isn't valid.